# SharePoint 2013 Upgraded from SharePoint 2010 - Unable to Edit Web parts on Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, upgrade

I can edit web parts on all pages except the home page.  I click page - edit and it appears to be in edit mode but there are no options on the web part title bar and I can't select edit web part.  I duplicated issue in Chrome, Edge and IE 11.

How can I edit the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homepage may be corrupted during the upgrade.

As a workaorund, you could use another page as a new home page. Thus you could edit web parts on home page.

Comment: I recreated the homepage.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the below troubleshooting approaches :

1. First try to check out the page then go for editing from home page.

Site Settings -> Site Content -> Site Pages ->then click on ellipses three dots "..." next to home page name -> Click on "..." -> Check out

Or

2. Open the page directly in edit mode through the URL by just appending "? =edit" at end of the page URL.

Or

3. If you are accessing the page URL through the alternate access mapping URL.... try to access the page using directly the server: port URL

Hope any of the above steps will fix the issue.